# Can you derive the Dirac equation from the Dirac-von Neumann axioms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation

The Dirac von Neumann axioms say nothing about relativistic QM, can I invoke relativistic effects and derive the Dirac equation from the Dirac von Neumann axioms?

If so, how does one go about it? If not what are the axioms I need to derive the Dirac equation?

Comment: You need to postulate two things: the Hamiltonian is linear in momenta and that the spectrum is R minus the open interval called mass gap

Comment: Why do you expect to get the spin-1/2 Dirac equation rather than the spin-0 Klein-Gordon equation, or the equations for spins 1, 3/2, or 2? They’re all relativistic quantum mechanics.